# Delete all text file content except one string chosen with C#

Tags: c#, text, replace, texttrimming

I have this txt file:

> ********** Welcome to file*********************This test file.It can gives value.It returns if the validation is successful or shows errors where the XML validation fails.It checks for syntax and content as well.****************************************************************2022-07-14 20:07:54,730 [INFO] textvalue- text  has been generated successfully2022-07-14 20:07:54,731 [INFO] neededvalue -  *** value needed = ARdBaG1lZCBNb2hhbWVkIEFMIEFobWFkeQIPMzAwMDc1NTg4NzAwM==

but these values `2022-07-14 20:07:54,730`  and `2022-07-14 20:07:54,731` are changeable and want to remove all text except this value `ARdBaG1lZCBNb2hhbWVkIEFMIEFobWFkeQIPMzAwMDc1NTg4NzAwM==` what ever the changeable values are changed!

I trying this code :

```
string remove = "********** Welcome to file*********************This test file.It can gives value.It returns if the validation is successful or shows errors where the XML validation fails.It checks for syntax and content as well.****************************************************************2022-07-14 20:07:54,730 [INFO] textvalue- text  has been generated successfully2022-07-14 20:07:54,731 [INFO] neededvalue -  *** value needed = ";
            
            var text2 = "";
            string resultt = string.Empty;
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\text.txt");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {

                if (line.Contains(remove))
                {
                    text2 = line.Replace(remove, "");
                    resultt = text2.Trim();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(text2);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

it gives me the value but when the changeable values are changes then the `remove` string not matches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to match content after "value needed = ".  Then it shouldn't matter what comes before.

A good pattern would be:

```
"(?<=value needed = ).+"
```

Which translates to:

- `(?<=value needed = )`: look for the term "value needed = " before some text
- `.+`: match any character that occurs any number of times.

Here is it's use in C#:

```
string text = "etc, etc, etc. ... value needed = ARdBaG1lZCBNb2hhbWVkIEFMIEFobWFkeQIPMzAwMDc1NTg4NzAwM==";
        
var regex = new Regex("(?<=value needed = ).+");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(text)?.Value);
// ARdBaG1lZCBNb2hhbWVkIEFMIEFobWFkeQIPMzAwMDc1NTg4NzAwM==
```